# Confused about Laplace Wave Equation Transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} u(x,t) -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} u(x,t) =f(x), \quad 0<x<1, \quad t>0\\ u(x,0)=0, \quad \frac{\partial}{\partial t} u(x,0)=0\\ u(0,t)=0, \quad u(1,t)=0$$
>   I am supposed to take the Laplace transform of the wave equation that yields a non-homogeneous ordinary differential equation in terms of $\mathcal{L} \{f(x)\}$ and $\mathcal{L} \{u(x,t)\}$ and its $x$-derivatives.
>
> Can someone please explain the relationship between the two functions, and how it's $x$-derivatives changes will be reflected in the function? This question was posed as a challenge question, and I am seeking some guidance.

How does one setup this Laplace transformation? Why is there $t$ and $x$ in the same system?

Comment: how can we singularly transform the t variable when we have x'' as well.

Comment: Likewise, this is my first time seeing IVP in a coordinate fashion. What does u(x,0) = 0 mean?

Comment: Just hold it constant. Should I be treating the u(x,t) terms as constants?

Comment: If you transform $t$ then I would keep $x$ but treat it as constant regarding the Laplace transformation.

Comment: Based on your suggestions, then do I simply just do L(t'')u(x't) = f'(x)? Do I completely ignore the x^2 term?

Comment: can this problem be rewritten as:
t''u(x,t) - x''u(x,t) = f(x)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not used Laplace transform a lot but I think that it would act similarly as the Fourier transform (the only difference is that Fourier transform acts on *position* variable, so $x,y,z,\cdots$ and Laplace transform acts on the time variable). With that in mind if you take the Laplace transform on both side of the equation you would get: $$\mathcal{L}\{\partial^2_{tt}u\}-\mathcal{L}\{\partial^2_{xx}u\} = \mathcal{L}\{f(x)\}\\ \color{red}{\mathcal{L}\{\partial^2_{tt}u\}}-\underbrace{\partial^2_{xx}\mathcal{L}\{u\} = f(x)\color{blue}{\mathcal{L}\{1\}}}_{\text{the transform acts only}\\ \text{on time so it's independent}\\ \text{of the }x}\\ \color{red}{s^2U(x,s)-su(x,0^+)-\partial_tu(x,t)|_{t=0^+}} - \partial^2_{xx}U(x,s)=\frac{f(x)}{\color{blue}{s}}$$
The red one follows from the [property of derivation for the Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) and the blue from the Laplace transform of $1$.

As you can see you began with an ode with two partial derivation and you arrived at a second order ode in the function $U(x,s)$. This means that one you've found the solution $U(x,s)$ you can directly find $u(x,t)$ by anti-transforming! If this isn't the most beautiful thing you've ever seen, I don't know what it would be!

Comment: Where is the derivation of large U coming from? Is there a substitution occurring that I am simply not realizing? The next step of the question is to find the solution of f(x) = sin(pi*x) but I don't understand how U can help solve for that solution

Comment: I've given you the Wikipedia link on the properties on the Laplace transform! The beautiful thing about transforms is that they act on derivatives in such a way as to eliminate them, making your *pde* in an *ode*

Comment: would the convolution work in the case of solving for solution when f(x) = sin(pi*x?

Comment: Let me try on a pice of paper! As I said I'm always working with Fourier transform and convolutions come up a lot, probably even in this case can help

Comment: hmm. I've never encountered the Fourier transform before in my assignments before, so I think I should be sticking to Laplace transformation

Comment: Doing some rough calculations it doesn't seem like the convolution would be of any help! Try solving it yourself. Note that the initial conditions $u(x,0)=0$ and $\partial_t u(x,0) = 0$ are useful in the transformed equations. If you substitute them you get $$s^2U - \partial_{xx}^2 U = \frac{f(x)}{s}$$ which is a simple equation, sort of an harmonic oscillator or probably something on the line of a Storm-Liouville system, but don't quote me on that

Comment: Hi Davide. Where did you get (x,0+) from?

Comment: From the properties of the Laplace transform of the derivative $$\mathcal{L}\{f^{(n)}(t)\} = s^{(n)}F(s) -\sum_{k=1}^n s^{n-k}f^{(k-1)}(0^+)$$

Comment: I see. So now that I have s^2U - d^2/dx^2U = f(x)/s. I directly plug in sin(pi*x) into f(x) since f(x) = sin(pi*x) in my next step. I isolate for U. Meaning .......u[s^2-d^2/dx^2) = sin(pi*x)/s.....Do I just divide that over and take the inverse Laplace? Or am I on the wrong track completely

However, I think I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Well, you have to be careful $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ it **isn't a number, it's an operator** you cannot divide by a derivative! Once arrived to the transformed equation you just have to solve a *second order linear partial differential equation in the variable x* with one of the myriad of methods that exists to solve them!

Comment: so the it would be the equivalent of saying ux''? Then how can I isolate the U if its attached to the operator

Comment: Nope, be carful $$\frac{d^2 U}{dx^2} = U''$$ sort of, if you want to look it that way

Comment: ohhhh I see. Then in this case, if f(x) = sin(pi*x)....then will the ODE be -U'' + s^2*u - sin(pi*x)/s = 0? Thank you for being so helpful and guiding me through this problem.

Comment: Sure it is! Happy to have been useful!

Comment: Can I just use quadratic formula to find the roots and get the general equation? I have form -1r^2 + s^2*r + constant (constant being = sin(pi*x)/s)...wait that wouldn't make sense. Should I be using the LaPlace transform instead?

Comment: Well this is a non-homogeneous ode..you should find the homogeneous solution (with the quadratic formula) and the particular solution with one of the tons of methods that exists. Just do a quick google search, for example http://www.solitaryroad.com/c657.html

Comment: Right. But my concern is how can we factor out roots if we don't have numerical coefficients since there is s^2 lurking in front of u. I know to find the solution, we have to find the complementary and the particular solution. But for the complementary, we have non real number coefficients. And for the particular solution, should our guess for the RHS be Asin(pi*x) + Bcos(pi*x)?

Comment: Because we are commenting too much on this post I highly recommend to write down your concerns on another MSE post, there many other people would get involved and we won't go against the forum rules

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81184/discussion-between-firemeup-and-davide-morgante).

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm on the phone now and pretty busy atm!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming $\mathcal{L}$ transforms the $t$ variable into the $s$ variable.
E.g. $u(x, t)$ into $U(x, s)$.

I added the $t$ subscript to the operator to indicate it acts on $t$.

The subscripts $xx$ mean second order partial derivative regarding $x$,
$tt$ mean second order partial derivative regarding $t$.

My guess would be:
$$
\mathcal{L}_t \{ u_{tt}(x, t) - u_{xx}(x, t) \} = \mathcal{L}_t \{ f(x) \} \iff \\
s^2 \, U(x, s) - s \, u(x, 0+) - u_t(x, 0+) - U_{xx}(x, s) = f(x) \mathcal{L}_t \{ 1 \}
$$

The idea is to apply the initial conditions here, then get an ordinary differential equation for $U$, solve for $U$ and then use the inverse Laplace transform to get a solution $u$.

Comment: Thank you for you response. Can you show how you got big U from s^2U?

Comment: So solving for U, then I would set up the equation as f(x)L{1} + su(x,0+) + ut(x,0+) = U(x,s) (s^2 - 1)? 

Then divide by s^2-1?